# Line 0 Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, oledb

I have inherited some code old asp/vb code and its throwing an error which I can't find a fix for.

The server is Windows Server 2008, its running IIS7 and the SQL server is 2008.

This is the code:

```
<% @ Language=VBScript %>
<!-- #include file="dsn.asp" -->
<!-- #include file="adovbs.inc" -->
<!-- #include file="libfunct.asp" -->

<%
'****************************************
'    VARIABLES DECLARATION
'****************************************
Dim sSql, RsInsCoInfo, PolicyID, InsCo, InsOffice
Dim qsPolicyType, qsAttach, qsCLNT_ID, qsClientID
Dim CostArray(10)
Dim DescriptionArray(10)
'****************************************
'    END VARIABLES DECLARATION
'****************************************


'********************************************
'    RETRIEVING THE QUERYSTRINGS
'********************************************
qsAttach     = Request.QueryString("Attach")
qsCLNT_ID    = Request.QueryString("CLNT_ID")
qsClientID   = Request.QueryString("ClientID")
qsPolicyType = Request.QueryString("PolicyType")
qsReQuote    = Request.QueryString("ReQuote")
qsPolicyID   = Request.QueryString("PolicyID")
'********************************************
'    END RETRIEVING THE QUERYSTRINGS
'********************************************


'**********************************************
' RETRIEVING THE INSURANCE COMPANY DETAILS
'**********************************************
'Get the insurance company details
Set RsInsCoInfo  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

sSQL = "SELECT InsuranceCo.*,FormPolicy.* FROM insuranceCo,FormPolicy"
sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE FormPolicy.INS_EF <= CONVERT(smalldatetime,'" & dbSaveDate(Date) & "',101)"
sSQL = sSQL & " And FormPolicy.INS_ET >= convert(smalldatetime,'" & dbSaveDate(Date) & "',101)"
sSQL = sSQL & " AND FormPolicy.PolicyType ='"  & qsPolicyType & "'"
sSQL = sSQL & " AND InsuranceCo.INS_ID = FormPolicy.INS_ID"

'response.write ssql
'response.end
RsInsCoInfo.Open sSQL, OLEDBConnStr, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

If Not RsInsCoInfo.EOF then
    InsOffice = RsInsCoInfo("INS_Office")
    InsCo     = RsInsCoInfo("INS_DS")
Else
    Response.write "<b>No underwriter available.  Please contact the system administrator.<br>"
    Response.write sSQL
    Response.end
End if

'Close and free
RsInsCoInfo.close
Set RsInsCoInfo = Nothing
'**********************************************
' END RETRIEVING THE INSURANCE COMPANY DETAILS
'**********************************************



'*********************************************************************************
'              CLIENT SEQUENCE NUMBER INCREMENT FOR THIS POLICY TYPE
'*********************************************************************************
If Not qsReQuote Then
   newPolicyNumber = qsClientID & qsPolicyType
   Set RsSequence    = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
   sSQL = "SELECT * FROM Policy WHERE PolicyNumber like '%" & newPolicyNumber & "%' AND Clnt_ID=" & qsCLNT_ID
   RsSequence.Open sSQL, OLEDBConnStr, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
   If RsSequence.recordcount > 0 then
       PolicyID = 00
       While not RsSequence.eof
          If right(RsSequence("PolicyNumber"), 2) > PolicyID then
             PolicyID = Cstr(right(RsSequence("PolicyNumber"), 2))
                response.write PolicyID & "<br>"
          End if
          RsSequence.moveNext
       Wend
       PolicyID = PolicyID + 1
       If PolicyID < 10 then
          PolicyID = "0" & CStr(PolicyID)
       End If
   Else
      PolicyID = "01"
   End If
   RsSequence.close
   SET RsSequence = NOTHING
End If
'*********************************************************************************
'             END CLIENT SEQUENCE NUMBER INCREMENT FOR THIS POLICY TYPE
'*********************************************************************************


'*********************************************************************************
'             UPDATING ADDITIONNAL FIELD TO THE QUOTE CREATION
'*********************************************************************************
'Setting var
Dim strConnection, SQL_Upsate, newPolicyNumber
newPolicyNumber = qsClientID & qsPolicyType & PolicyID


If Not qsReQuote Then
   'Insert Sql Statement
   SQL_Update = "UPDATE Policy SET CLNT_ID=" & qsCLNT_ID & ","
   SQL_Update = SQL_Update & " InsuranceCo='"& InsCo & "',"
   SQL_Update = SQL_Update & " Office='"& InsOffice & "',"
   SQL_Update = SQL_Update & " StatusID="& 0 & ","
   SQL_Update = SQL_Update & " PolicyNumber='" & newPolicyNumber & "'"
   SQL_Update = SQL_Update & " WHERE PolicyID=" & qsAttach
Else
   'Insert Sql Statement
   SQL_Update = "UPDATE Policy SET CLNT_ID=" & qsCLNT_ID & ","
   SQL_Update = SQL_Update & " InsuranceCo='"& InsCo & "',"
   SQL_Update = SQL_Update & " Office='"& InsOffice & "',"
   SQL_Update = SQL_Update & " StatusID="& 0
   SQL_Update = SQL_Update & " WHERE PolicyID=" & qsPolicyID
End If


'Connection object and open the db
Set strConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection.Open OLEDBConnStr

' Executing the sql insert
strConnection.Execute SQL_Update

'Now Close the connection and free up
strConnection.Close
Set strConnection = Nothing

'*********************************************************************************
'               END ADDING ADDITIONAL FIELDS TO THE QUOTE CREATION
'*********************************************************************************


'*********************************************************************************
'                               DO CALCULATION
' - obtains file named Policy & 'Calculations.inc' = HHCalculations.inc etc.
'
' Modified by Stuart 20/5/03
'*********************************************************************************
set Rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

If Not qsReQuote Then
   sSQL = "SELECT Policy.* FROM Policy WHERE Policy.PolicyID=" & qsAttach
Else
   sSQL = "SELECT Policy.* FROM Policy WHERE Policy.PolicyID=" & qsPolicyID
End If

Rs.Open sSQL, OLEDBConnStr, adOpenkeyset, adLockPessimistic, adCmdText



'********************************************
'Response.write "<B>Policy table For Testing Only<P></b>"
'For Each fld in Rs.fields
'   Response.write fld.name & " = " & fld.value & "<br>"
'Next
'Response.end
'**********************************************

    Agent = 0
    Agent2 = 0
    AgentIntro = 0

'Open rsAccount for writing account entries to the PolicyAmount table
'** Comment derek to Stuart -> wont we be better here to find the agent with the code?

If Session("Agent") <> "" then
    set RsAgent = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    sSQL = "Select * from Agents Where Name = '" & Session("Agent") & "'"
    RsAgent.Open sSQL, OLEDBConnStr, adOpenkeyset, adLockPessimistic, adCmdText
    Agent = rsAgent("commission")
End if


'If a park was involved for a new business then the introductory rate is required.
If Session("Village_Name") <> "" then
    set RsPark = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    If IsNumeric(Session("Village_Name")) Then
       sSQL = "Select * from Park Where ParkID = '" & Session("Village_Name") & "'"
    Else
       sSQL = "Select * from Park Where ParkID = '" & Session("reParkID") & "'"
    End If
    RsPark.Open sSQL, OLEDBConnStr, adOpenkeyset, adLockPessimistic, adCmdText
    If RsPark.eof then
        Response.write "<b>" & ssql & "<P>No Park record found - Line 189 QuoteSave2.asp<P>Please contact you system administrator." 
        'Response.end
    Else
        AgentIntro = RsPark("Introduction")
    End if
End if

set RsAccount = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
set RsQuestions = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

If Not qsReQuote Then
   sSQL = "SELECT * FROM PolicyAmount WHERE PolicyID=" & qsAttach
Else
   sSQL = "SELECT * FROM PolicyAmount WHERE PolicyID=" & qsPolicyID
End If
RsAccount.Open sSQL, OLEDBConnStr, adOpenkeyset, adLockPessimistic, adCmdText

If Not qsReQuote Then
   sSQL = "SELECT * FROM PolicyQuestions WHERE PolicyID=" & qsAttach
Else
   sSQL = "SELECT * FROM PolicyQuestions WHERE PolicyID=" & qsPolicyID
End If

RsQuestions.Open sSQL, OLEDBConnStr, adOpenkeyset, adLockPessimistic, adCmdText

If Not qsRequote Then
   RsAccount.Addnew
End If
If Not qsRequote Then
   RsAccount("PolicyID") = qsAttach
   linkID = qsAttach
Else
   RsAccount("PolicyID") = qsPolicyID
   linkID = qsPolicyID
End If


sTargetFile = qsPolicyType & "Calculations.inc"
sTargetFileContents = GetFileContentsForExecution(sTargetFile)
Execute sTargetFileContents




'*********************************************************************************
'                            END DO CALCULATION
'*********************************************************************************





'*********************************************************************************
'                            WRITE COSTS TO THE TABLE
'*********************************************************************************

'Update data to the PolicyAmount table
RsAccount("PolicyAmount_IB") = Session("Login")

RsAccount("PolicyAmount_IT") = Date
RsAccount.Update

'**********************************************
'Response.write "<P><B>PolicyAmount table For Testing Only<P></b>"

'For Each fld in RsAccount.fields
'   Response.write fld.name & " = " & fld.value & "<br>"
'Next
'Response.write "<P><B><a href='default.asp'>Home</a>"
'Response.end
'***********************************************

'Clean up
RsAccount.Close
Set RsAccount = Nothing
Rs.update
Rs.Close
Set Rs = Nothing
RsQuestions.Close
Set RsQuestions = Nothing
'RsPark.close
'Set RsPark = Nothing

'Finish with this second saving so redirect to the policy page
If Not qsReQuote Then
   Response.redirect "Policy.asp?PolicyID=" & qsAttach & "&CLNT_ID=" & qsCLNT_ID & "&ClientID=" & qsClientID & "&PolicyType=" & qsPolicyType
Else
   Response.redirect "Policy.asp?PolicyID=" & qsPolicyID & "&CLNT_ID=" & qsCLNT_ID & "&ClientID=" & qsClientID & "&PolicyType=" & qsPolicyType
End If

%>
```

This is the error: "Warning: File /quotesave2.asp Line 0 Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.. ."

It really doesn't give me much to go on and any help/insight would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Your code has serious SQL Injection attack vunerablity, never concatenate text received from the client into SQL code always use parameterised queries.  In fact in this case you should separate code that mutates the database and move it to SQL place it in a stored procedure with some transaction control (your code has concurrency issues as well) and then generate HTML output to the client afterward.

Comment: This code is run on an intranet that is only accessible by less than 15 people, its a non-issue. Its also not my code but something I was given to fix and not enough time to rewrite.

Comment: Just an idea - Does the underlying SQL tables have triggers? ive seen this error before when errors occur in the trigger.

Comment: What is your connection string? Please post the value of `OLEDBConnStr` probably defined in some included file..

Answer (score 0):

It's real tough to pin down the exact issue with no line number.  I noticed towards the end of the script, you are adding a new record to `RsAccount` and assigning values to the recordset fields.  In the past, I have gotten the "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors" error due to type mismatches between the VBScript variable and the recordset field type.  Double-check the data type of the columns that you are updating, and if necessary, explicitly convert values before assigning them to the recordset (for example, using `CLng` for numbers).

Answer (score 0):

This is classic, i handle these problems by logging each command to the db just before executing. So eg

```
log(sSql)
RsAccount.Open sSQL, OLEDBConnStr, adOpenkeyset, adLockPessimistic, adCmdText
```

Where log(tekst) is a sub which writes to a txt file the passed text. Now when you encounter an error execution stops and you check your log. The last entry is the sql generating the error. Execute this sql in an interactive environment where you can easily adjust the text and try again and where you get more accurate error from your dbclient. Don't know what it is for Sql Server, i use Oracle and there it is Sql*Plus, i'm sure there must be others for Sql Server. Once you corrected your sql, paste it in your code, replacing your literals with variables. Request your page again and do the above until all your sql is correct.

Answer (score 0):

First, your SELECT statement is selecting multiple field with same name which might cause a problem. Change your statement to this: (You might need to change the table of INS_DS, I just guessed)

```
sSQL = "SELECT ic.INS_Office, fp.INS_DS "&_
    "FROM insuranceCo ic INNER JOIN FormPolicy fp ON ic.INS_ID = fp.INS_ID "&_
    "WHERE fp.INS_EF <= CONVERT(smalldatetime,'" & dbSaveDate(Date) & "',101) "&_
    "AND fp.INS_ET >= convert(smalldatetime,'" & dbSaveDate(Date) & "',101) "&_
    "AND fp.PolicyType = '"  & qsPolicyType & "'"
```

If still same error, I remember getting this one when messing around with Date/Time fields so those two date fields are suspects. For sake of debug try to select without that filter and see what happens:

```
sSQL = "SELECT ic.INS_Office, fp.INS_DS "&_
    "FROM insuranceCo ic INNER JOIN FormPolicy fp ON ic.INS_ID = fp.INS_ID "&_
    "WHERE fp.PolicyType = '"  & qsPolicyType & "'"
```